# Is localhost host resolved to 127.0.0.1?

Tags: windows, loopback

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is “127.0.0.1 localhost” needed  in HOSTS file ?](https://superuser.com/questions/178292/why-is-127-0-0-1-localhost-needed-in-hosts-file)

Is localhost host resolved to 127.0.0.1?

If "yes", then why does everything (IIS , ASP.NET, MS SQL Server, webapps, sharepoint, etc.) work on my WIndows XP Pro SP3 exactly the same if I use 127.0.0.222 (or any loopback IP 127.0..0.*) instead of 127.0.0.1?

Is localhost well-known Windows identifier?

Comment: Added Update1 and Related questions

Comment: @vgv8: please don't add unnecessary (un)related links to your question. Readability of the question is severly impacted

Comment: @moderator, I cannot post any question in SU, MSU, SO, as well as edit my posts. Is it intentional?

Comment: Submitting question in SU, SO, MSU fails with: " Oops! Your question couldn't be submitted because:

users with less than 100 reputation can only post questions every 20 minutes; try again later." though I had not submitted any question for the last 24 hours

Comment: @vgv8: Moderator swill not be updated by commenting on your question, only Sathya will and he is not a moderator as he doesn't wear a diamond after his name. You could place your problem on the [meta site](http://meta.superuser.com/) so that a moderator sees it or contact team@superuser.com if it's really urgent.

Comment: @TomWij. thanks but I have exactly the same issue on all sites (from which I am not banned), including MSU, i.e. posting there is also rejected with the same message. I wrote: "Submitting question in SU, SO, MSU fails with: " Oops!" They are the only sites from which I am not banned in trilogy (i.e. I am banned from MSO and MSF)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Loopback](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loopback) device (aka Locahost) is mapped to the whole range of `127.0.0.0` to `127.255.255.255`, which is why it `127.0.0.222` works:

> The most commonly used IP address on the loopback device is 127.0.0.1 for IPv4, although any address in the range 127.0.0.0 to 127.255.255.255 is mapped to it.

**Update**

See [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb727005.aspx) article on host name resolution (specific to 2003, but should apply to XP).

Possibilities:

- Your DNS server is responding with `localhost` for any `127.*` query (unlikely)
- The entry is still cached (`ipconfig /flushdns` to clear it out)
- You may have an `lmhosts` file that maps it

I have seen that the default `networks` file in windows contain `loopback 127`, which may be why this works.

It is also quite possible that the mapping `loopback / localhost` is built into the TCP/IP stack itself.

Comment: Thanks for try but see my Update1 in main question

Comment: @vgv8 - see my update. Perhaps this will provide a better answer.